# Estimates for $|| \cdot ||_{p}$ and $|| \cdot || _{q}$ norms on $C[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality, normed-spaces

Well, i would like to find a minimal constant $C_{a, b, p, q}$ which depends only on $a, b, p, q$ so that the following inequality holds $|| \cdot ||_{p} \leq C || \cdot ||_{q}$, where $1 \leq p \leq q < \infty$ and $$||f||_{p}=(\int_{a}^{b}{|f|^{p} dx})^{\frac{1}{p}}$$

Probably, it's possible to make a good use of the the Holder and Minkowski inequalities, but i can not see more or less direct approach in how to complete it. Are there any hints that might help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Holder inequality to show
$$
\|f\|_p^p = \int_a^b 1 \cdot |f|^p dx \le \left( \int_a^b (|f|^p)^{q/p}\right)^{p/q} \left(\int_a^b 1 \right)^{1-p/q}
= (b-a)^{(q-p)/q} \|f\|_q^{p},
$$
hence
$$
\|f\|_p \le (b-a)^{\frac1p-\frac1q} \|f\|_q.
$$
With $f=1$ you get equality, hence $C_{a,b,p,q}=(b-a)^{\frac1p-\frac1q}$ is optimal.